# VB6 - comboboxes lost focus

Tags: combobox, vb6, lost-focus

I'm working on a VB6 project and I cam across something that I'm unable to resolve. In my project I'm using 2.0 comboboxes. Everything works fine, in terms of loading the combobox with data, selecting it, and the whole bunch. What I'm trying to do is, once data has been selected, I'm making sure that the same data has not been selected in both comboboxes. I'm trying to write a quick comparison IF statement in LOST FOCUS for one of the cbo's but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Private Sub cbo1_LostFocus() 
if cbo1.text<>"" and cbo2.text<>"" then
    if cbo1.text = cbo2.text then
        MSGBOX "Duplicate Values"
    else
        exit sub
    End if
end if
End Sub
```

it doesn't at all realize there is LOST FOCUS - I don't think I've ever done that to a cbo, usually textboxes and such. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try GotFocus instead. It seems the LostFoucs event can be overridden or masked in certain cases. This article shows a similar problem: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?396536-RESOLVED-VB6-LostFocus

Of course, you could always upgrade to the latest VB, but I'm guessing you have your reasons.

Comment: I'm maintaining a legacy vb6 application. GotFocus I already have for a different reason. LostFocus does not fire at all, neither does Validate.

Comment: You could always put this code into a separate function and call it inside your GotFocus. Unless you're saying that your existing GotFocus code interferes with this functionality.

Comment: I guess that could be done also. I'm really trying to do it when it loses focus, because this way I can select one value in cbo1 then after selecting a values in cbo2 - i check if both are the same. I just tried CHANGE and it works, but LOST FOCUS would help me more because it would continuously remind them that the values are different - so they don't accidentally save it. With Change, I use a msgbox to tell user they have 2 values - but that's it.

Comment: Could you try adding a third non-cbo component and see if LostFocus fires when you switch focus to that component?

Comment: What I'm doing is letting the user press a look up button, where another window opens up, they select an item and it puts it in the cbo (they can also just click the triangle and they see the items, but there are a lot of them which is why i'm doing the look up). Once I select an item and press TAB that's when LostFocus fires.

Comment: is there a way for me to somehow code it so that TAB gets hit - which would fire lost focus

Comment: Have you tried the SetFocus method? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa244175(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: i don't think SET FOCUS will help in that case - seeing as I need to tab off the combobox in order to fire the LOSTFocus. Thanks, appreciate your input!